I need to implement a button which when clicked will switch to a third person camera of the sphere and follow it as it moves
Basically what the title says, I need to implement a button which when clicked will switch to a third person view of the sphere and follow it as it moves, but have no idea how to achieve this. Been stuck at this and any help would be greatly appreciated.
Using react-three-fiber for my project
import { Canvas, useThree } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { useGLTF, Stage, OrbitControls, Text} from "@react-three/drei";
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { Mesh, PlaneGeometry, MeshBasicMaterial, Vector3, Line, BufferGeometry, LineBasicMaterial, Float32BufferAttribute } from 'three';
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function Model(props) {
  const { scene } = useGLTF("/platformnew2.glb");

  scene.traverse((child) => {
    if (child.isMesh) {
      child.material.color.set('#91b7cf'); // Light Steel Blue color
      child.material.roughness = 0.5; // Adjust roughness to make it less shiny
      child.material.metalness = 0.1; // Adjust metalness to give a more natural look
    }
  });

  return <primitive object={scene} {...props} />;
}

function UserSphere(props) {
  const sphereRef = useRef();

  return (
    <>
      <mesh ref={sphereRef} position={props.position}>
        <sphereGeometry args={[0.1, 32, 32]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial color="#FFA500" />
      </mesh>
      {/* Floating 3D label */}
      <group position={[props.position[0], props.position[1] + 0.2, props.position[2]]}>
        <Text
          position={[0, 0, 0]} // Position for "Current"
          fontSize={0.05}
          color="#000000"
          anchorX="center"
          anchorY="middle"
          rotation={[0, 0, 0]} // Adjust rotation if needed
        >
          Current
        </Text>
        <Text
          position={[0, -0.05, 0]} // Position for "Position" below "Current"
          fontSize={0.05}
          color="#000000"
          anchorX="center"
          anchorY="middle"
          rotation={[0, 0, 0]} // Adjust rotation if needed
        >
          Position
        </Text>
      </group>
    </>
  );
}

// Define a curved path
function CurvedPath({ points, color }) {
  const pathRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pathRef.current) {
      const curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(points);
      const tubeGeometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry(curve, 256, 0.02, 8, false);
      pathRef.current.geometry = tubeGeometry;
    }
  }, [points]);

  return (
    <mesh ref={pathRef}>
      <meshStandardMaterial color={color} />
    </mesh>
  );
}

function CameraSetup() {
  const { camera } = useThree();

  useEffect(() => {
    camera.position.set(-5, 2, 4); // Set initial camera position
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0)); // Ensure camera looks at the model
  }, [camera]);

  return null;
}

function App() {
  // Define the points for the path
  const points = [
    new THREE.Vector3(-2.5, 0.4, -5),
    new THREE.Vector3(0.4, 0.4, -5),
    new THREE.Vector3(2, 1, -5),
    new THREE.Vector3(2, 1, -6.6),
    new THREE.Vector3(0.4, 0.4, -6.6)
  ];
  return (
    <Canvas
      dpr={[1, 2]}
      shadows={false}
      style={{ position: "absolute" }}
    >
      {/* Adding ambient and directional lights */}
      <ambientLight intensity={0.2} />
      <directionalLight position={[5, 10, 7]} intensity={0.4} />

      <color attach="background" args={["#B0D4F1"]} />

      <Stage environment={"night"} intensity={0.7} shadows={false}>
        <Model scale={0.01} receiveShadow={true} castShadow={true} color="#4682B4" />
        {/* Add the user sphere on the platform */}
        <UserSphere position={[-2.5, 0.4, -5]} />
        <CurvedPath points={points} color="#0000FF" /> {/* Blue path */}
      </Stage>

      {/* OrbitControls for interaction */}
      <OrbitControls
        enableZoom={true}
        enableRotate={true}
        enablePan={true}
        maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2} // Limit rotation to avoid flipping
        minPolarAngle={0} // Limit rotation to avoid flipping
        zoomSpeed={1.2}
        panSpeed={0.8}
      />

      {/* Custom camera setup */}
      <CameraSetup />
    </Canvas>
  );
}

export default App;

